# расположение Custom Badgies на UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Использую библиотеку [ckteebe/CustomBadge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge)

Все настроил сам badgies и добавляю его к кнопке по вычислению размера кнопки `frame.size.widh` ( пишу в xcode 7 под ios 9) кнопка создана в Interface builder, а badgies добавляется программно к кнопке 
`[_buttonTexts addSubview:badgeText];`
На 5 iPhone все нормально отображает (вехний правый угол) но на других моделях съезжает (на 6 айфон правее и т.д.)
Как можно настроить его так чтобы badgies был на всех кнопках распределен одинакого в верхнем правом углу?

Comment: Предоставьте код, где Вы выставляете ее frame.

Comment: `CustomBadge *badgeTask = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"12"];
    [badgeTask setFrame:CGRectMake(_buttonTask.frame.size.width/2, -18, 30, 30)];
    [_buttonTask addSubview:badgeTask];`

Comment: Вы случайно это не во viewDidLoad делаете?

Comment: Именно в нем, а где нужно?

Comment: Попробуйте перенести во viewWillApear

Comment: попробовал, эффект тот же

Comment: пробуйте выставлять border, и распечатывайте фреймы и бейджа и  кнопки, смотрите, в какой момент изменяется фрейм

Comment: на 5м и 6м кнопка разного размера, по этому `_buttonTask.frame.size.width/2` приводит к разному результату

Comment: тогда как сделать чтобы для каждого? делать проверку на девайс и ставить это значение в зависимости от устройства?

Comment: @Northex можно и так, это не запрещено.

Comment: нет, так делать не надо

Answer (score 1):

вместо `_buttonTask.frame.size.width/2` вам надо ставить в правый верхний угол для любого устройства:

```
CustomBadge *badgeTask = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"12"];
[badgeTask setFrame:CGRectMake(_buttonTask.frame.size.width-18, -18, 30, 30)];
[_buttonTask addSubview:badgeTask];
```

не уверен насчет -18 - взял то же значение, что у вас в origin.y

Comment: Эх, не хорошо же использовать числа, не хорошо))

Comment: программа не моя - единственное что вижу, это фреймы. надо как то выкручиваться

Comment: да знаю, знаю))

Comment: код не мой, я только разместил фикс :)

Comment: Вот скрин ![Картинка](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=4344167c6bf314078bc3c8f6f5804e78).
где 12 это сделано 

`CustomBadge *badgeTask = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"12"];

[badgeTask setFrame:CGRectMake(_buttonTask.frame.size.width-18, -18, 30, 30)];

[_buttonTask addSubview:badgeTask];`


где остальные баджеты это 

`CustomBadge *badgeTask = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"12"];

[badgeTask setFrame:CGRectMake(_buttonTask.frame.size.width/2-18, -18, 30, 30)];

[_buttonTask addSubview:badgeTask];`

Comment: @Northex и что на ней должно быть видно?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Баджет с надписью 12 должен быть в правом верхнем углу кнопки "Все задачи"

Comment: @Northex а какой у ввас фрейм этой самой кнопки?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko 275x40

Comment: @Northex а весь экран в ширину 375. то есть у вас кнопка 2/3 экрана занимает, хотя визуально меньше половины. Давайте наверно вы начните с того, что кнопку приведите в нормальный вид, а потом уже и бэдж поставим как надо.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko хорошо, мне кажется я понял в чем проблема в wAny  hAny. попробую настроить на книжный вариант